# Replacing ng-app with bootstrap call in AngularJS 1.4

Tags: angularjs

I'm following the path for ng-upgrade and one of the steps is to replace the ng-app with a call to bootstrap.

At the moment the code does a

```
<html data-ng-app="app">
```

And I tried to replace that (leaving an empty html tag behind) with this

```
<script>
    angular.element(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app'], { strictDi: true });
    });
</script>
```

But the page is not rendered. No error is shown, I've tried a couple of different things here, but to no avail.

Any hint?

Update1:

I tried to change it to

```
<script>
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app'], { strictDi: false });
    });
</script>
```

With the same result.

Comment: Is there any other code present in your program? can you please show us that as well?

Comment: Sure. Can you tell me which bits exactly? It's a fairly big program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are using jQuery, with AngularJS v1.4.x you should use `angular.element(document).ready(...)`.

In v1.6 `angular.element(fn)` was introduced as an alias (and preferred alternative of) `angular.element(document).ready(fn)` (following latest jQuery conventions), but in earlier versions passing a function to `angular.element()` will not work.

See, also, this **[short demo](https://codepen.io/ExpertSystem/pen/gGJPYX?editors=1000)**.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that, still not working. I updated the question to include the code I switched to

Comment: It should :) There is not much we can do to help without a reproduction. Try to create a minimal reproduction of your issue using CodePen, Plnkr or something similar. I added a runnable example in my answer (you can use that as a starting point).